# creating different bitmaps in loop

Tags: bitmap

i am trying to create a list of bitmaps, where i am creating one bitmap, then changing the content of a combobox, and through that changing the content of every text box.

I am using the code seen below:

```
bitmap = new Bitmap(1500, 800);
            using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                gr.CopyFromScreen(this.PointToScreen(Point.Empty), Point.Empty, new Size(1500, 800));
            }
            bitmaps.Add(bitmap);


            if (cykler_.Count > 1)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < cykler_.Count; i++)
                {
                    BikeCountCB.SelectedIndex = i;

                    Thread.Sleep(200);
                    bitmap = new Bitmap(1500, 800);
                    using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                    {
                        gr.CopyFromScreen(this.PointToScreen(Point.Empty), Point.Empty, new Size(1500, 800));
                    }
                    bitmaps.Add(bitmap);
                }
            }
```

```
private void BikeCountCB_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 

            for (int i = 0; i < cykler_.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i == BikeCountCB.SelectedIndex)
                {
                    cykelstorelseCB.Text = cykler_[i].cykelstorelse;
                    sadelBreddeforCB.Text = cykler_[i].sadelBreddeFor;
                    SadelBreddeEfterCB.Text = cykler_[i].sadelBreddeEfter;
                    SkoRTB.Text = cykler_[i].sko;
                    saalerRTB.Text = cykler_[i].saaler;
                    pedalerKlamperRTB.Text = cykler_[i].pedalerKlamper;
                    ModelRTB.Text = cykler_[i].Model;
                    TypeCB.Text = cykler_[i].type;
                    sadelHojdeCB.Text = cykler_[i].sadelhojde;
                    setBackCB.Text = cykler_[i].setBack;
                    reachGrebCB.Text = cykler_[i].reachGreb;
                    reachMidtStyrCB.Text = cykler_[i].reachMidtStyr;
                    dropCB.Text = cykler_[i].drop;
                    frempindGraderCB.Text = cykler_[i].frempindGrader;
                    frempindLaengdeCB.Text = cykler_[i].frempindlaengde;
                    styrBreddeCB.Text = cykler_[i].styrBredde;
                    styrDybdeCB.Text = cykler_[i].styrDybde;
                    styrReachCB.Text = cykler_[i].StyrReach;
                    krankarmCB.Text = cykler_[i].krankarm;
                    KnaevinkelCB.Text = cykler_[i].knaevinkel;
                }

            }
```

My problem is that every bitmap turns out identical, like the content of the form doesnt change.

Hope someone can spot the mistake

Comment: Try using a timer instead of that loop.  The form doesn't have any time to refresh, and that sleep is a blocking call, get rid of it.

Comment: I am not sure how you want me to use a timer instead of the loop? can you describe it a bit more, because i have never really used the timer. Thank you!

Comment: You might be able to get away with replacing the `Thread.Sleep(200);` line with `this.Refresh();`